# SQL insert select statement

Tags: c#, sql, select, insert

I want to insert 4 values in the table call SKU. In this case I want to pass one value from another table while I have 3 value from the text box.

```
insert into [dbo].[Sku] (skuid, clientid, skudesc, [Type]) 
values (test, clientid, test, physical)

select Clientid 
from [dbo].[Client] 
where clientname like 'Admin';
```

Could you please suggest me?

Thank you

Comment: string sql = string.Format(
                "insert into [dbo].[Sku] (skuid,clientid,skudesc,[Type]) values ({0},{1},{2},{3})" +
                " select Clientid from [dbo].[Client] where clientname like 'Admin';",
                textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `insert into .. select ..` syntax, but the values you want to get from the text box needs to be as part of the select clause:

```
insert into [dbo].[Sku] (skuid,clientid,skudesc,[Type])  
  select 'test' as skuid, clientid, 'test' as skudesc, 'physical' as [type]
  from [dbo].[Client] where clientname like 'Admin';
```

Comment: Thank you  @Nir Levy Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
    Create procedure procName
    (
        @test int,
        @clientid int
    )
    As
    Begin

    insert into [dbo].[Sku] (skuid,clientid,skudesc,[Type]) 
    values (@test,@clientid,@test,
    (select Clientid from [dbo].[Client] where clientname   like 'Admin'))

    End
```